# Programatically retrieve Android Organization/Enterprise ID

Tags: android, android-enterprise

I'm looking for a way to programatically retrieve the Android Organization/Enterprise ID (https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/distribute#add_an_enterprise_to_alphabeta_tests) in an App that is enrolled to an organization and was pushed onto the device through a managed Google Play Store.

I already checked the Android Developer Guides but cound't find anything on this topic.

Comment: Can you tell more about your use case? Why do you need a programmatic way to get the ID from the app? Are you the developer of that app, or is it any app?
Also note that if you are an admin of the organization you can get the ID from play.google.com/work.

Comment: We want to implement a licensing system and need a unique id for each organization. It is possible to generate a license key and push it to the device, but the enterprise id would be more straight forward as it exactly identifies what we are looking for.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately only the admin of the organization can know the ID. Some organizations also have a domain (G Suite organizations) but the mapping is not public, and other organizations don't have a domain and the ID is the only identifier of the organization therefore there is nothing to map from.